Definition of dual abelian schemes
Let $A$ be an abelian scheme on $S$
Let $\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}$ be the relative Picard functor.
For many authors, the dual abelian variety is the identity component of the relative Picard functor (which I denote $\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}^{0}$) which is representable.
However, I recently started reading the book "Neron Model" and inside they define the dual abelian scheme as the open subscheme of $\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}$ given by $\mathcal{P}ic_{A /S}^{\tau}:=\bigcup_{n}n^{-1}(\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}^{0})$.
I then tried to look at mathstackexchange and mathoverflow but people consider the two definitions without distinction (see for example the different answers in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118989/the-dual-abelian -scheme) ). I therefore suppose that in the case of an abelian scheme
$$\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}^{0}=\mathcal{P}ic_{A/S}^{\tau}.$$
Question
1- Is this isomorphism true?
2- Is it trivial? If so, can you give me the reason?
3- Otherwise can you give me a reference?
